# Typescript TS2532: Object is possibly 'undefined' even though I'm actually checking

Tags: typescript

I have this weird issue where I don't understand why Typescript keeps complaining about a possible undefined value:

[image: Webstorm error]

```
if (!flatListRef || !flatListRef.current) return

flatListRef.current.someMethod()
```

This code returns the same error:

```
if (flatListRef && flatListRef.current) {
    flatListRef.current.someMethod()
}
```

So does this piece of code:

```
flatListRef?.current?.someMethod()
```

And also this:

```
flatListRef!.current!.someMethod()
```

I'm running Typescript 4.3.5 targetting `es6` and have no idea why TS2532 keeps popping. I've tried upgrading all my packages but I have no clue on how to debug this issue. Any hints would be greatly appreciated :-).

My tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": false,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "jsx": "react-native",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es6",
    "lib": [
      "esnext",
      "dom"
    ],
    "skipLibCheck": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "include": [
    "App.js",
    "app",
    "test",
    "storybook"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Try enabling `strictNullChecks` compiler option (or even its wider alternative `strict`) – it may be the issue here, because the code itself seems absolutely valid

Comment: Are you sure  `someMethod()` cannot be undefined?

Comment: What is `current`? A field? A getter?

Comment: @NikitaIvanov You are right, `strictNullChecks` needed to be set to true. Thanks, please create an answer so I can mark it :).

Comment: @JoshGreifer Yes, `someMethod()` is not a valid method but it doesn't matter for this example.

Comment: @Lesiak Ah, I'm sorry -- it's a React ref. I didn't think it was needed to include it here, but could have done it for brevity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(from a comment above)

`strictNullChecks` flag should be enabled. If it's not, I suppose that `tsc` ignores all typeguards that are used to check that a variable is not `null` (and `undefined`)